# Implementing a loop for a system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I am new here and with Python. I am working on a code for numerical solutions of ordinary differential equation systems.
My problem: I need to implement a loop inside a function. After that, I need to integrate that function (odeint), but it doesn't work.

Here is the (working) code without the loop:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import * # for plotting commands
def deriv(y,t): # return derivatives of the array y
    a = 2.0
    return array([ y*a*(1-y/10)]) 
time = linspace(0,500,1000)
yinit = 1 
y = odeint(deriv,yinit,time)
figure()
plot(time,y)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

And here is the non working code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import * # for plotting commands
def deriv(y,t): # return derivatives of the array y
    a = 2.0
    for i in range(0,10):
        return array([ y[i]*a*(1-y[i]/10) ]) 
time = linspace(0,500,1000)
yinit = linspace(1,1,10) 
y = odeint(deriv,yinit,time)
figure()
plot(time,y[:,0],time,y[:,1])
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

Can Someone help me?

Comment: Could you please document what the differential equation in the second case is? You should return an array of length 10, you are returning an array of length 2 in the i=0 loop of the corrected version. There is no obvious way to repair it.

Comment: I'm just trying to solve systems of ODEs with "n" equations. i am a biologist. i am simulating a system with "n" populations, and each population refer to one equation.

Comment: Yes, but what are the equations? In the first case, n=2, there are 2 equations for two components. But in the second case, where n=10, you try to assemble 10 pairs of functions, making it 20 in total. Except that the first return returns just a single pair. Without further knowledge there is no way to repair it in a meaningful way.

Comment: ok, i am posting one more simple set of equations, in order to keep the focus on the code problem.

Comment: I went looking for examples of non-trivial systems for odeint and found nothing. Also, it is inconsistent if (numpy/scipy) arrays objects are needed or just the naked [1,2,3] arrays, both can be found. I put 5 identical Voltera-Lotka systems in my answer below, this should be easily extensible, with or without loop, to truly coupled systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation and examples for using odeint with more than 4 dimensions or complicated functions are really rather sparse. A working implementation for 5 (independent) Voltera-Lotka systems with a total dimension of 10 could look like this:

```
from scipy import zeros_like
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import * # for plotting commands

def deriv(y,t): # return derivatives of the array y
    a = 2.0
    b = 0.5 #0.1
    c = 0.1
    doty = zeros_like(y)
    for i in range(0,5):
        j=2*i   # this has no deep reason
        k=2*i+1 # just keeps notation short
        doty[j] = y[j]*a*(1-y[j]/10)-b*y[j]*y[k]
        doty[k] = b*y[j]*y[k]-c*y[k]

    return doty

time = linspace(0,500,1000)
yinit = linspace(1,1,10) 
y = odeint(deriv,yinit,time)
figure()
plot(time,y[:,0],time,y[:,1],time,y[:,5],time,y[:,8])
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code, your syntaxing was off:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import * # for plotting commands
def deriv(y,t): # return derivatives of the array y
    a = 2.0
    b = 0.5 #0.1
    c = 0.1
    for i in range(0,10): #INSERT A COLON HERE
        return array([ y[i]*a*(1-y[i]/10)-b*y[i]*y[i], b*y[i]*y[i]-c*y[i] ]) #INDENT THIS
time = linspace(0,500,1000)
yinit = linspace(1,1,10)
y = odeint(deriv,yinit,time)
figure()
plot(time,y[:,0],time,y[:,1])
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

Your error was here:

```
for i in range(0,10)
return array([ y[i]*a*(1-y[i]/10)-b*y[i]*y[i], b*y[i]*y[i]-c*y[i] ])
```

You are supposed to put a colon after the `for` statement, and indent the `return`:

```
for i in range(0,10): #INSERT A COLON HERE
    return array([ y[i]*a*(1-y[i]/10)-b*y[i]*y[i], b*y[i]*y[i]-c*y[i] ]) #INDENT THIS
```

Comment: Is that really useful? the function returns within the first loop at i=0, i=1 is never reached.

Comment: it made the code work without errors messages (at least that!). But, it solves only one equation. It seems that the loop is not working as it should be! What is wrong?